# quitting testNG tests programmatically

Tags: testng, selenium-webdriver

How can I quit the complete test suite programmatically if a certain condition is met?

I am checking for the condition in @AfterMethod and using the fail() method to fail the AfterMethod annotation. But the AfterMethod annotation gets executed as many times as the number of tests in my Test suite. The tests are skipped however.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you,

John

Comment: Not quite sure i understood your question, what you are looking for is breaking a running test suite in the middle of runtime if some specific scenario is met? With a success?

Why bother building other tests?

Comment: I want to quit the tests completely as this check is for checking something is running in the background but I cant check it until the tests starts.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to reply, i was on vacation. So if i get it is you want to stop the tests of running in case a condition fails?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just my thought

Call afterClass annotation method in afterMethod annotation method if your condition met & stop your java process in afterClass.

```
public class NewTest {

    @BeforeClass
      public void beforeClass() {
          System.out.println("In before class");
      }

      @BeforeMethod
      public void beforeMethod() {
          System.out.println("in before method");
      }

      @Test
      public void test1()
      {
          System.out.println("in test1 method");

      }
      @Test
      public void test2()
      {
          System.out.println("in test2 method");

      }
      @AfterMethod
      public void afterMethod() throws Throwable {
          System.out.println("in after method");
          if(condition)
          {
              afterClass();
          }
      }

      @AfterClass
      public void afterClass() throws Throwable {
          System.out.println("in after class ");
          System.exit(0);
      }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Santosh, I will try what you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The @AfterMethod annotation triggers after every test method in the test. But if you want to validate conditions after each test method this is the right annotation.

But if you want to do it after all methods being executed use @AfterClass

Just putting System.exit()  is a not good practice. Once you exit test it will not produce any test teardown actions and report generation. Clean way to do this is skipping the test once you find such a scenario.

You can use testng SkipException for that . Please see the code below for sample

```
  @AfterMethod
      public void afterMethod() throws Throwable {
          if(CONDITION_MET==true)
          {
             throw new SkipException ("Skipping Test: ");
          } 
      }
```

Thank you,
Dharsnana

Comment: Hi Dharshana, Thanks for your reply. I don't want to skip but quit with a report generated :) so that I can tell developers that certain service is not running and they can turn it on, coz if this service is not running there is no point continuing testing. Cheers.