# Programmatically stop TestNG run

Tags: java, testing, automation, testng

I develop some GUI in which user can start and stop TestNG tests.

Can I anyhow stop TestNG process without creating conditions check in `@AfterMethod` cause some tests are very long (more than 15 minutes) so `@AfterMethod` solution is not effective. There is **NO** requirements to stop tests **gracefully**.

Are there any solutions in the latest TestNG versions (>7.0)?
For example, with the help of `IExecutorFactory` or `ITestRunnerFactory`?

References:

- [quitting testNG tests programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859844/quitting-testng-tests-programmatically)
- [How to stop TestNG executioner when exception occures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917223/how-to-stop-testng-executioner-when-exception-occures)
- Stop test execution: https://groups.google.com/g/testng-users/c/FhC3rqs1yDM

Answer (score 1):

Since you rely on GUI to start and stop the tests, I assume the presence of `start` and `stop` methods.

In the `start` method, you create an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) which would execute the tests programmatically and in the `stop` method you could shut down this executor.

Also, note that it is recommended that you do some mechanism to share the `ExecutorService` between `start` and `stop`. Otherwise it would cause trouble if multiple test runs(continuous start operations) are allowed through GUI.

```java
public class MyClass {
    private ExecutorService ex;

    public static void testRunner() {
        TestNG t = new TestNG();
        t.setTestClasses(new Class[] {YourTestClass.class});
        t.run();
    }

    public void start(){
        ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        ex.execute(MyClass::testRunner);        
    }

    public void stop(){
        ex.shutdownNow();
    }

}
```